# Random integer secret generated for DH in TLS?

Tags: ssl, https, cryptography, tls1.2, diffie-hellman

From my understanding, the client and the server would generate two random secrets that they would use to computer the shared key in DH for TLS. But how is this done? What algorithm does it use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Comment: Both generate a key pair and then send the public key. The randomization is automatic because the key pairs are random.

Comment: How is the randomization done? Does it use entropy?

Comment: what function does the browser use to call the random number generator from the operating system and  which part of the keys are generated using the random numbers